# I want to get all textbox values using jquery and make them all null on onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all values within a form using jQuery 
and want to set all those as a value null.

Now I have text also and hidden fields also.

```
<input id="MYNAME_04cd1197-7147-4b82-9b0a-c44846405150" 
       type="text" 
       value="MyName"/>

<input id="MYID_12cd1112-7147-4b82-9b12-c412846125112" 
       type="hidden" 
       value="f208b514-133b-4d6d-8299-f5f002e131a0"/>
```

There are many textboxes like this.

May I know what is the syntax to get all these textboxes and set `null` as value to `[type="text]"`
and `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` to `[type=hidden]` inputs.

I tried something like:

```
  function resetAllValues() {
        debugger;
        $('#TransactionGrid').find("input:text").each(function (index) { });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('form > input').val('');
```

But this everyone will tell to you in different ways.
What you should know is:

Your html element must have the attribute NAME, if you want to get all the values from the form(as you commented). You can't use $('#frm1').serialize() for example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#TransactionGrid').find("input[type='text']").each(function (index) {
   //get value
   var val = $(this).val();
   //set this value to ''
   $(this).val('');
   //to hide
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks and where and how to assign values to `null` or `empty guid`

Comment: edit answer with some method to set, get and hide @ashuthinks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TransactionGrid').find("input[type=\'text\']").each(function (index) {
```

//Setting the value to null i.e '';

```
 $(this).val('');
```

//if u want to hide it u can use .hide...

```
    $(this).hide();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
 function resetAllValues() {
         $("input:text", "#TransactionGrid").val('');
         $("input:hidden", "#TransactionGrid").val('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
}
```

Comment: inside  function resetAllValues() ? directly ?