# How to find Controls using Web Page Object?

Tags: asp.net

Here is code

```
private void Get_Controls() 
{

     _Default def = new _Default();

     for (int i = 0; i < def.Controls.Count; i++)
     {

     }

}
```

I have controls in Default.aspx but Count gives me 0.

Comment: Where do you call this?  `_Default def = new _Default();` will not give you a copy of the page you're trying to examine - it will make a new instance, and depending on where you are in the page's lifecycle the control count may very well be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead writing long Code

**Finding Controls Recursively**

```
private Control FindControlReqursive(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            Control result = FindControlReqursive(control);

            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result is TextBox )
                {
                    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)result;
                    myTextBox.Text = "";
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        return parent.FindControl(controlId);
    }
```

**Calling**

```
// controlId is id of the control u want to find 
//eg. i m finding label inside page

 TextBox myLabel=FindControlReqursive(Page);
```

Comment: how can i call this function.

Comment: i am confusing about parameters FindControlReqursive(string controlId, Control parent);

Comment: I wanna give type, not id.

Comment: @user3493321 then you need to check type inside recursive function.wait i will update

Comment: i wanna get all textboxes and set them empty. Or placed their values in an object etc

Comment: @user3493321 updated now it does all textboxes inside page blank

Comment: @user3493321 i will suggest you can use jquery find each text box and clear it. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991862/i-want-to-get-all-textbox-values-using-jquery-and-make-them-all-null-on-onchange

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  foreach (var control in this.Controls)
  {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below one.

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
    {
        if (childc is TextBox)
        {
            allTextBoxValues += ((TextBox)childc).Text + ",";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already applied this code. To find controls using foreach I apply 10-12 loops, than it gives me controls.

```
private void Refresh()
{
    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control childe in childc.Controls)
            {
                if (childe is DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl)
                {
                    foreach (Control childf in childe.Controls)
                    {
                        foreach (Control childg in childf.Controls)
                        {
                            foreach (Control childh in childg.Controls)
                            {
                                foreach (Control childi in childh.Controls)
                                {
                                    foreach (Control childj in childi.Controls)
                                    {
                                        foreach (Control childk in childj.Controls)
                                        {
                                            foreach (Control childl in childk.Controls)
                                            {
                                                if (childl is TextBox)
                                                {
                                                    ((TextBox)childl).Text = "";
                                                }
                                                else if (childl is                    DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxTextBox)
                                                {
                                                    ((DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxTextBox)childl).Text = "";
                                                }
                                                else { }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of this i posted try that one